# Alternative to Bump Technologies API?

Tags: api, mobile

I need an easy solution for one mobile phone to trigger another one or a PC and "make a connection", at an event. I have no need for big data transfer.
I think Bump was the ideal solution for this, but now Google has completely discontinued it.

Does anyone have a view on the possibilities? I can see the following with following disadvantages:

- each phone can show a unique QR-code on the screen and the other one
  can scan it: is slow and quite cumbersome
- send an SMS or other message like WhatsApp: cumbersome
- connect with NFC: I guess the installed base of NFC is still below 50%
- put an RFID sticker on the mobile phone and hold it against a reader: cumbersome
- go to a website and push a button: cumbersome for the end user
- Is it possible to have a WiFi connection between 2 phones?
- Sense BlueTooth, but I understand this is only accessible on a jailbroken iPhone, and it consumes quite a bit of power...
- using sound, as Chirp does: seems unreliable in noisy environment and power consuming

Is there any other solution that provides the same technological solution as Bump does?
Does anybody know if their could be a way to still use Bump technology?

Answer (score 0):

Alljoyn is also can be used to share data across multiple platform. u can download its sdk with samples.